# Sub-query in eloquent with concat

Tags: subquery, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I'm new laravel 5.3 and facing sub queries problem with eloquent. i don't know how to write sub-query using eloquent. My query is given below.

```
select concat(m, '-', y), total
FROM (
    select  month(`date`) as m , year(`date`) as y,  round(sum(amount)) as total 
    from `budget` 
    where 
        `user_id` = 1 and 
        `amount` is not null  
    group by m, y
) as t
```

This is working fine in MySQL . so how can we convert this query in eloquent. so kindly solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create the sub query first you can merge the bindings in the parent query:

```
$sub = Budget::selectSub('month(`date`)', 'm')
    ->selectSub('year(`date`)', 'y')
    ->selectSub('round(sum(amount))', 'total')
    ->where('user_id', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('amount')
    ->groupBy('m', 'y');

$data = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as t"))
    ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
    ->selectRaw("concat(m, '-', y)")
    ->addSelect('total')
    ->get();
```